# Stop Controller Activity OperationId being flowed to sent messages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a web api core 2.1 application with a single controller. This controller takes a single Post with no properties. I use this Post as a way to start some functionality. When I receive the Post, I call a function that spawns multiple Tasks that each have a delay and then send a message via an HttpClient. This basically mimics multiple devices sending data to my endpoint. What I have found is that the OperationId from the original Post is being flowed through to all the sent messages. This functionality is not what I want, as when viewed from app insights, all the sent messages link together as they all use the same  OperationId. What I want to do is have a unique OperationId used in each message sent via the single HttpClient.

Here is some of the code that is used to delay the sending of the messages. The "heartbeat" object that is not shown, just adds the relevant message text then does a SendAsync to the passed in HttpClient.

The StartWork function is called multiple times via a "for" loop that is invoked by the original Post.

```
    private async Task StartWork(IHeartbeat heartbeat, int heartbeatInterval, CancellationToken cancellation)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_rnd.Next(1, heartbeatInterval)), cancellation);
        await DoWork(heartbeat, heartbeatInterval, cancellation);
    }

    private async Task DoWork(IHeartbeat heartbeat, int heartbeatInterval, CancellationToken cancellation)
    {
        if (!cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await InvokeHeartbeat(heartbeat, cancellation);

            Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(heartbeatInterval), cancellation)
                .ContinueWith(t => DoWork(heartbeat, heartbeatInterval, cancellation), cancellation);
        }
    }

    private async Task InvokeHeartbeat(IHeartbeat heartbeat, CancellationToken cancellation)
    {
        if (!cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await heartbeat.Send(_client, _host, _stopwatch, _logger, cancellation);
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to modify the OperationId for each message sent in the “InvokeHeartbeat” function?

For clarity, the OperationId I am talking about is the one that can be viewed using the following:

```
Activity.Current.Id;
```

[image]

Comment: How, and where are you managing this `Activity.Current.Id;`?

Comment: I added the code to view the ID in the controller's Post handler. I wanted to see what is was when the Post arrived and confirmed it is set in every message I view in app insights.

Comment: Maybe there's something here you can use: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource/src/ActivityUserGuide.md. Particularly the "Creating child activities" section.

Comment: @HansKilian Your link provided me with the information I needed. Not sure if you need to add this as a separate answer so I can select it as the answer that worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create new activities to get different ids on your outgoing calls.

Check this documentation out: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource/src/ActivityUserGuide.md

Particularly the "Creating child activities" section.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Before each send I created a new “activity” and set the parent id to a new Guid.